# Best way to show a full screen Ajax loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I'm using a set of templates to develop my site which has this [search page](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/traveler/demo_v1_7/hotels.html).

The template also comes with this [loading page](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/traveler/demo_v1_7/loading.html) which I'd like to show when I'm performing an Ajax update of the search results.

All the Ajax fetch and display of the results is working. I just need to know of a good technique to display the loading HTML whilst it's fetching the new results.

The technologies I'm using are HTML, Jquery, ASP.Net, MVC.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Put the template in your search and hide it and on ajax request show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the page in your search page, and hide it

You can use jQuery to check if the Ajax call is working, and while it is you can fade in the loading page, and fade it out if it's done loading.

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done.
Hidden the loader page html in the search page then used jquery to set the required classes and show/hide it.